# Connecting to Mobile Network via Mobile Broadband API

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7, mobile-broadband-api

I am trying to connect to a mobile network via a modem and a sim card. Every time I try to set the APN String and User Credentials in a Context via `SetProvisionedContext()` I get the `E_INVALIDARG` `HRESULT`. 
As Parameters I used an Instance of `MBN_CONTEXT`, a `wchar_t*` in form of `&std::vector<wchar_t>[0]`, and a `ULONG*`.

```
    MBN_CONTEXT context;

    std::vector<WCHAR> apnVector;
    inParamAPN.GetCString(apnVector);

    std::vector<WCHAR> userNameVec;
    inParamUsername.GetCString(userNameVec);

    std::vector<WCHAR> passwordVector;
    inParamPassword.GetCString(passwordVector);

    context.contextID = MBN_CONTEXT_ID_APPEND;
    context.contextType = MBN_CONTEXT_TYPE_INTERNET;
    context.accessString = &apnVector[0];
    context.userName = &userNameVec[0];
    context.password = &passwordVector[0];
    context.compression = MBN_COMPRESSION_NONE;
    context.authType = MBN_AUTH_PROTOCOL_PAP;
```

and later when I have the `IMbnConnectionContext`:

```
    std::vector<WCHAR> providerVector;
    InParamProvider.GetCString(providerVector);
    ULONG requestID;
    contextInterface->SetProvisionedContext(context, &providerVector[0], &requestID);
```

So my Question is: Which Parameter does the WinAPI have a Problem with, and how can I fix it?

Also any Tips of additional Sources for Information are appriciated. 
All I have so far are the official [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323271(v=vs.85).aspx) and the Code Example contained in the Windows 7 SDK. Are there any further sources of Information I am not aware of? A google search didn't yield the hoped for results.

Comment: So if I find the Documentation lacking I can not ask for help here?
Okay, let me specify my question real quick.

Comment: You just need to phrase it slightly differently. Instead of "Where do I find documentation on X?" you ask "How do I do X?". Try to avoid general questions like "How do I write a program?" and provide a [mcve] that shows the exact problem.

Comment: I think I did somewhat better now. Also Syntax Highlighting is not so good with WinAPI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end I did not get it working as it should. I used the second way of connecting to a custom APN, by making a new connection profile. For this I used a XML filled with the Values I needed.

Along the way I encountered another problem with an unforseen Error Code which I described [here](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/de-DE/d749a199-2ea4-4884-9267-49d61e7fc982/problem-with-mobile-broadband-connection?forum=windowssdk).

Best regards,

Stefan